# AWS RDS query via db's port connection vs. HTTPS

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

**Background**

I'm creating a Terraform module that provisions a Postgres database running on an AWS RDS Aurora serverless cluster and AWS Lambda and Codebuild services that need to read/write to the database. The contents of the database contain sensitive information.

**Problem**

For the CodeBuild and Lambda services, I'm debating between using a database client such as [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) that connects via port 5432 (Postgres) or a database client such as [aurora-data-api](https://pypi.org/project/aurora-data-api/) that connects via a database HTTP endpoint. Given that this database contains sensitive information, the biggest factor in choosing is security.

Here's a list of tradeoffs I've found so far and I was wondering if I missed anything before I make a decision.

**psycopg2**

pros:

- Services that connect to the database can be locked down via security groups rules
- Able to use `psycopg2` which handles dynamic SQL queries fairly well

cons:

- Requires management of security credentials within the services directly
- Requires opening port 5432 for the subnets/security groups associated with the database
- Given this is a Terraform module, users of the module can decide to not host the Lambda function and Codebuild projects within the associated VPC that the database is hosted in. If these services are hosted within another user-defined VPC, that would require VPC peering configurations. If they don't use a user-defined VPC, this would require the user to figure out the IP range of the services in relation to the AWS region the services are created in to define the ingress security group CIDR range for the database.

**aurora-data-api**

pros:

- Uses AWS IAM authentication to define permissions for connecting to the database. This opens up the ability to use fine-grained IAM policy conditions for connecting/querying the database (currently not needed but possibly in the future).
- Uses AWS Secret Manager for passing credentials to the database client without having to directly define credentials
- Doesn't require opening any ports
- Able to connect outside of VPC without having to provision an EC2 or Lambda function with proper VPC configurations for running queries (useful for running test locally)

cons:

- Not able to use `psycopg2` which handles dynamic SQL queries fairly well

Comment: Are you aware that the data API is only available for Aurora Serverless clusters at this time?

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's serverless, ill update the post. Thanks  @MarkB

Comment: I think you've got a good handle on the pros/cons. At this point it seems like you just need to weigh the pros/cons for your specific scenario and pick the path you want to go with. I'm not sure anyone can give you a "correct" answer to your question except yourself.